# Adding a language in a dropdown under product information

Tags: magento-1.8, product, admin, attributes

[image]

How can I add a just a language name in the above shown dropdown? This can be found under catalog > manage products > click on any product > general.

So the purpose of this is to show on website like below,

[image]

Comment: You can Create a Attribute and assign the attribute @Norway_Ambiance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Follow These steps

Step 1:Create attribute **Catalog > Atrribute > Manage Attribute > Add new 
Attribute**

Take A look Of the below screen shot

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2651475/777038c939b3598c2b36110cbe11b8f3

Step 2: Assign the created attribute to the Product type Under  **Catalog > Atrribute > Manage Attribute Set > Add new 
Attribute Set**

Then in Product creation page see a below screen shot

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=2651469

Put these code in Your Template File To get Attribute Value

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Your Product Id);
$language = $product->getAttributeText('Your Attribute code');
foreach ($language as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer, it's pretty simple, thanks Pranay K for your initial direction.

Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Click on language > choose Manage Label/Options from right > Click add option`